# Calculate image dimensions on screen size before rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way of calculating / estimating what the image size would be depending on the screen resolution before the image has been rendered? I need more logical help rather than code to be honest. What do I need to calculate?

Image size: 800px * 450px

Window size: 424px * 728px

The image works out to be 424px * 239px. I need to calculate this in code so I can adjust positions of other elements following after (absolute / fixed elements).

What I have done so far is;

```
var ratio1 = (this.retrievedNewsArticle.featuredImage.width / this.retrievedNewsArticle.featuredImage.height);
var ratio2 = ($(window).innerWidth() / this.retrievedNewsArticle.featuredImage.width);

// Ratio 1 = 424
// Ratio 2 = 0.53
```

So what's next?

Comment: Where is the logic currently for making  the image 424 * 239? Seeing as the image is sized to the windows size, there is probably CSS  or javascript making the image scale to that. Maybe you should work some magic in that section rather than calculating all this stuff.

Comment: @Glubus: Looks like full width, maintaining aspect ratio. But would be better if stated explicitly.

Comment: Your post is confusing, you mention at first "before the image has been loaded" and then you talk about "I need to calculate this before I render the HTML". Which is it?

Comment: @rugdealer you are right; it's just not rendered. It's full width image in CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you already know the image's size, and it sounds like you want the image to be the full width of the window, and just need to know how to determine the height of the image. If so, the target height is the image height times the windows width divided by the image width:

```
var renderedWidth = imageWidth;
var renderedHeight = imageHeight * (windowWidth / imageWidth);
```

That maintains the aspect ratio.

That assumes the image is always wider than the screen. Let's remove that assumption.

If you want the image to stretch to fill:

```
var renderedWidth, renderedHeight;
if (windowWidth >= imageWidth) {
    renderedWidth = imageWidth * (windowWidth / imageWidth);
} else {
    renderedWidth = imageWidth;
}
renderedHeight = imageHeight * (windowWidth / renderedWidth);
```

If you don't want the image to stretch to fill:

```
var renderedWidth, renderedHeight;
if (windowWidth >= imageWidth) {
    renderedWidth = imageWidth;
    renderedHeight = imageHeight;
} else {
    renderedWidth = imageWidth;
    renderedHeight = imageHeight * (windowWidth / imageWidth);
}
```

Comment: Unsure if this should be taken into account but he mentioned "but I need to calculate this before I render the HTML", it's unclear where he has added his script. Otherwise +1

Comment: `var renderedHeight = imageHeight * (windowWidth / imageWidth);` was the maths I needed. I might of not put the words together correctly in my question but that is what I was looking for.